# Insert Property Value using Py2neo

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2neo

I have one label say User,and one property say Email.I am trying to insert one property value based on user input like *"abcd@gmail.com"* . My code is below

```
db=Graph("bolt://localhost:1234", user="", password="")
db.evaluate('''Create (u:User) WHERE u.Email=$para1 RETURN u''',
                                         parameters={'para1': arg}))
```

I am tried also

```
db.create(Node("User", "Email").__setitem__("Email", arg))
```

However both is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.Posting the answer so it may help others.

```
self.db.evaluate('''Create (u:User) SET u.Email=$para1 RETURN u''',
                                         parameters={'para1': arg})
```